# Regular expression to match html tags

Tags: html, regex, tags

Just wanted to know if this the right way to write a regular-expression for an opening Html-tag `<strong>` : `/<strong[^>]*/i`?

What I am trying to do is have a pattern in place for html tags and then use is to match any html document.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags :-)

Comment: meta: [Please stop linking to the “Zalgo” / anti-Cthulhu regex rant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182189)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272).

Answer (score 0):

Close.

It would be like this for the opening tag:

```
/<strong[^>]*?>/i
```

<sub>Keep in mind that using Regex on HTML which involves tags nested within themselves can get very messy.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Ok. What I understood is that You want to match any string between "<" and ">" symbols. for an example `<codekaro>`

To do so you can use :

```
^[\<][A-Za-z]*[\>]$
```

Here, ^ indicates start of an expression,

[\<] will check for one occurrence of < symbol, \ is used as escape character for < symbol

[A-Za-z]* will check for any string,

[>] will check for one occurrence of > symbol, \ is used as escape character for > symbol

$ indicates end of an expression.

I encourage you to use [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for regex tutorial and [this link](http://regexpal.com/) to check results of regular expression.

Hope this will help you..!!

Happy learning..!!